# EaselJS, how to position Container , Text center to canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, easeljs

For Bitmap object, I can get the width and height easily on the Image object. then I can set the regX, regY to 1/2 of width or height. Then I can center the Bitmap to Canvas.

But, I don't know how to do it on Container , Text object...How can I ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Containers don't have a width or height, so in that case you would have to calculate the width and height from its' child-pobjects (if those are all bitmaps or bitmapanimations)

For the Text you can use `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Text.html